# Lotus Notes Dialog box with Minimize option

Tags: dialog, lotus-notes, minimize

I have Lotus notes Dialog box.. Is there any option to give minimize option for dialog box?

```
@DialogBox( form ; [AUTOHORZFIT] : [AUTOVERTFIT] : [NOCANCEL] : [NONEWFIELDS] : [NOFIELDUPDATE] : [READONLY] : [SIZETOTABLE] : [NOOKCANCEL] : [OKCANCELATBOTTOM] : [NONOTE] ; title )
```

The syntax does not have an option for minimize.  (like a general minimize option for any other windows )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to desgin a table in the form and put your field, button and so on inside the table. over the option [SIZETOTABLE], the table is then similar to the size of the dialogbox.

I hope this answer your question.

if you like to minimize your dialogbox and work in an other domino window, this doesnt work in the domino enviroment. the dialogbox is the current window which have to be close before you can do something else in the domino enviroment.